# Hide/display content depending on whether Slick navigation arrows are showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have two [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carousels on a page, one with thumbs that controls the main slider. Sometimes the slider can have a lot items and we'd like to be able to expand the carousel by clicking on a link so that all thumbs are visible instead of having to use the left and right arrows to navigate back and forth. When you click the link again, it collapses the thumbs back into a carousel.

That's all working fine. What I want to do though is only show the link to expand/collapse if the arrows are visible because sometimes there's not enough thumbs to expand anything.

I've looked through the [events](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#events) and [methods](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#methods) but don't see anything I can use to do something like:

```
if(slickArrowsAreVisible) {
  do stuff
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to find an button element in `slick` carousels. Following this code,

```
//arrow doesn't exist
if (slick_instance.find('button.slick-arrow').length == 0) {
    //do stuff
  alert('No arrow');
}
//arrow exists
else {
    //do stuff
  alert('arrow');
}
```

Above code, only working when button element exists in domready state. if button element create or destroy dynamically, you could use `MutationObserver` or `DOMNodeInserted`.

if you use `DOMNodeInserted`

```
$('.slick').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
  //do stuff
});
$('.slick').bind('DOMNodeRemoved', function(e) {
  //do stuff
});
```

or `MutationObserver`

```
function mutation(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
        if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
        //do stuff
      }
      else if (mutation.removedNodes.length) {
        //do stuff
      }
    }
  });
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(mutation);
observer.observe(elem, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an `init` event where you can grab the number of slides pretty easily. I used this in a fiddle to do what I think you're looking for.

I'm not using "if the arrows are visible", I'm using "number of slides vs slides to show setting" (if that makes sense). (Also, note that there are no arrows here, but you can drag-slide the top one).

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2kb8vmyv/

And, the `init` event code I'm using:

```
    $el.on('init', function(event, slick, direction) {
        var slideCount = slick.$slides.length;
        if (slideCount <= show) {
            $('.expand[data-for="' + selector + '"]').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This works well but I've chosen the other answer because I won't know exactly how many thumbs are showing at different screen sizes.

Comment: That makes sense. The other answer answers your question more directly. Thanks for the +1 :)